# Cropping form in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to display a specific part of a webbrowser and I want to do that with an option to crop the form. Basically, when you resize a form it automatically affects the webbrowser, I want to somehow disable that and be able to crop the form. (winforms)

Comment: You can't do this via the WebBrowser (or any other) control, unless the part you want to crop to happens to be an `iframe`. The closest you might get is a large WebBrowser control, with some panels layered over top so only the important part remains... but that's gonna get real awkward to display effectively.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? I was personally thinking of displaying that specific part of the form but I couldn't make that aswell.

Comment: You could try downloading the HTML separately (via system.net.webclient) and filtering the html string down to just the part you need, but this is unlikely to work well. Probably what you'll need to do is a full web scrape... find how how/where this form submits, provide your own controls, and send your own HTTP post using system.net.httpwebrequest.